# Не могу понять, почему при нажатии кнопки приложение сворачивается

Tags: android, activity

Написал симулятор гармони.

**Как оно выглядит:**
[image: Как оно выглядит]

**Сейчас хочу сделать для пользователей пример.**
Хочу при нажатии "кнопки 1" воспроизводить ноты и изменять текст на кнопках.
Для этого создал новый класс `MyTask`, в нём поток и вызываю его из обработчика кнопки. Ещё на каждой кнопке висит обработчик, если пользователь хочет просто поиграть на гармошке.

В симуляторе андроид студио всё работает.
Когда запускаю на своем смартфоне, при нажатии "кнопки 1", приложение сворачивается и становиться не активным, но не закрывается и не виснет и его можно найти в списке запущенных программ и сделать активным.

Может быть дело в версиях андроида и часть функций в моей версии андроида на смартфоне не поддерживается?

Помогите тогда в этом вопросе разобраться.

По ссылке проект.

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/j2tt/DA6Jaf8xt

Ниже код класса и функция его вызова:

MyTask mt;

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //myButton1.setText("Begin");
        }


        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1);

                time_nota = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(EditText1.getText()));

                myButton3.setText("3");
                myButton3.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b3,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Ми_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton3.setText("Ми");
                myButton3.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton6.setText("2");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b6,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Ля_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton6.setText("Ля");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton5.setText("3");
                myButton5.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b5,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Соль_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton5.setText("Соль");
                myButton5.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton6.setText("2");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b6,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Ля_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton6.setText("Ля");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                //такт2
                myButton7.setText("4");
                myButton7.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b7,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Си_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton7.setText("Си");
                myButton7.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton6.setText("2");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b6,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Ля_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton6.setText("Ля");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton5.setText("3");
                myButton5.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b5,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Соль_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton5.setText("Соль");
                myButton5.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton6.setText("2");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b6,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Ля_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton6.setText("Ля");
                myButton6.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                //такт3
                myButton5.setText("4");
                myButton5.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b5,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Соль_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota*2);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton5.setText("Соль");
                myButton5.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                myButton4.setText("2");
                myButton4.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b4,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Фа_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                //myButton4.setText("Фа");
                myButton4.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                //такт4
                //myButton4.setText("2");
                myButton4.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE69B63);
                streamID = sounds.play(b4,1.0f,1.0f,1,0,1);//Фа_1
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota*3);
                sounds.stop(streamID);
                myButton4.setText("Фа");
                myButton4.setBackgroundColor(0xFFBBEEE7);

                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time_nota);


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //myButton1.setText("End");
        }
    }

    public void button1(View view)
    {
         mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас банальный NPE. Само по себе приложение не будет сворачиваться, если вы явно это в коде не прописали. Посмотрите в логи при "сворачивании" приложения. Скорее всего  оно просто падает.

Comment: Нельзя менять UI из фонового потока (метод `doInBackground()`). Наверное стоит познакомиться с классом `Handler` и примерами его использования - думаю для этой задачи он больше подойдёт, чем `AsyncTask`.